# Highlight a word in webpage using XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to look for a word TEST using XPath and highlight it. I have managed to search for the word TEST using `var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'TEST')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;`

How do I highlight this result TEST in webpage itself? Thank you

Comment: How do you want to "highlight" the result? Add a class or style to the parent element?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to add a style as a highlight

Comment: Do you want to highlight the complete text node? Then wrap it into a `span` element and style that as needed. Otherwise split the text node and wrap that word into the span. The Range API can help with that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting the returned text node contents:

```js
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'TEST')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
var node = xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node != null) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(node);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'highlight';
  range.surroundContents(span);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: strong;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a TEST.</p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
```

Highlighting the substring:

```js
var term = 'TEST';

var xpathResult = document.evaluate(`(//text()[contains(., '${term}')])[1]`, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
var node = xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node != null) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(node);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'highlight';
  range.setStart(node, node.data.indexOf(term));
  range.setEnd(node, node.data.indexOf(term) + term.length);
  range.surroundContents(span);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: strong;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a TEST.</p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
```